# Spring boot not serving empty / zero-byte static assets

Tags: spring-boot

I have a standard Spring Boot application with an embedded Tomcat web server and without any special configuration. According to the default config, static resources are served from `src/main/resources/static`.

However, I have the problem that a `404 Not Found` is returned if the files a empty, i.e. 0 bytes in size. This happens only when I run the packaged JAR. That is, when I run the application with `mvn spring-boot:run`, everything works and a `200` is returned for the empty file. However, if I do `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage` and then execute the JAR, an error is returned for those empty files. All other static files (more more than 0 bytes in content) work fine. Also, all files – including the empty ones – are present in the JAR under `BOOT-INF/classes/public/static`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `src/main/java/resources/static`? They are served from `src/main/resources/static` which is a whole different directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant. I'll update the original post.

Comment: That took a while to find, but it appears to be standard behavior of Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16034. Why is it working when not inside a JAR? No idea, maybe the repackage labels the files differently. Quick fix: add a space or line-break to the empty files.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev Thanks a lot for finding that issue! The files are auto-generated by the build process of a frontend application, so inserting a blank space there would be a bit cumbersome. It would be cooler to be able to override some resource loader class or so to consider empty files valid. I'll keep searching.

Comment: This happens if you try and serve an IonicJS frontend packaged into a sprint-boot  web application. Apparently one of the files is meant to be empty: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1840

Comment: Stumbled across the same behaviour. The empty files are the result of a frontend build. Did someone found a solution other than postprocessing the empty files?